# Passing list names as argument to izip

Tags: python, list, arguments, python-itertools

I have number of lists that is user defined

```
numLists = sys.argv[1]
d = [[] for x in xrange(numLists+1)]
```

I'm performing some operations on these lists and I want to pass them at the end to `itertools.izip` in the following format, for example if the user entered numLists = 2

I want the line to be

```
  for val in itertools.izip(d[0],d[1],d[2]):
    writer.writerow(val)
```

Usually if I already have some predefined lists `A[], B[]`

The line will be

```
  for val in itertools.izip(A,B):
    writer.writerow(val)
```

Is there a way to pass the list names into `izip`?

NOTE:

I do not want to do this 
    for j in range(numLists): 
       for val in itertools.izip(d[j]):
          writer.writerow(val)

because it does not give the needed output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Unpack*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the list of lists into positional arguments of `izip()`:

```
for val in itertools.izip(*d):
```